# UWP don't load the UI data from code

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I would like to fill my page from code side.
My page xaml code is here:

```
<Hub x:Name="MainPageHub" Grid.Row="1" >
                    <HubSection x:Name="HomeHub" Header="Home" DataContext="{x:Bind m_people, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <GridView x:Name="PeopleGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
                                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:PeopleViewModel">
                                        <StackPanel Background="DarkGray" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image Width="50" Height="50" Source="{x:Bind PictureUrl, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                            <TextBlock FontSize="15" Text="{x:Bind Happening, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" Orientation="Horizontal"></ItemsWrapGrid>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            </GridView>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HubSection>
                  </Hub>
```

I try to do this for the loaded event, but the ObservableCollection don't update the UI.
MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private ObservableCollection<PeopleViewModel> m_people { get; set;}

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += Page_Loaded;
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            m_people = new ObservableCollection<PeopleViewModel>();
            m_people.Add(new PeopleViewModel {Happening = "vaalam", DateTime = DateTime.Now, PictureUrl = "Assets/Data/Picture/1.png"});
            m_people.Add(new PeopleViewModel {Happening = "vaalam", DateTime = DateTime.Now, PictureUrl = "Assets/Data/Picture/2.png" });
            m_people.Add(new PeopleViewModel {Happening = "vaalam", DateTime = DateTime.Now, PictureUrl = "Assets/Data/Picture/3.png" });
        }
```

But when i fill the m_people collection in the MainPage(), it works. Why doesn't the Page_Loaded work?

Comment: As you add the event listener after the initializecomponent, it may not call the Page_loaded function because the page has already been loaded when the event is initialize

Comment: I tried to switch the two line, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! The problem was the `private ObservableCollection<PeopleViewModel> m_people { get; set;}`

I had to change for `private ObservableCollection<PeopleViewModel> m_people = new ObservableCollection<PeopleViewModel>();`

Sorry for this unwanted question!